# Argument 1 passed to ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array object given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am programming in Symfony 4.4.

I have a Recipe entity with a categories property. When I try to make a recipe record using a form in the database, it gives me the following error:

Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_final_daw\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 675

I use and NEED a ManyToMany relationship. I can't change this type to relationship.

**UploadRecipesType form**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Recipe;
use App\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class UploadRecipesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title',TextType::class,[
                'label' => 'Titulo',
            ])
            ->add('image',FileType::class,[
                'label' => 'Imagen',
            ])
            ->add('description',TextareaType::class,[
                'label' => 'Descripción',
            ])
             ->add('categories',EntityType::class,[
                 'class' => Category::class,
                 'mapped' => true,
                 'label' => 'Categoria',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
             ])

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Recipe::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Recipe.php Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RecipeRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RecipeRepository::class)
 */
class Recipe
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="recipes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $score;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $visible;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="recipe")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="recipes_categories")
     */
    private $categories;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getScore(): ?int
    {
        return $this->score;
    }

    public function setScore(?int $score): self
    {
        $this->score = $score;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVisible(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->visible;
    }

    public function setVisible(bool $visible): self
    {
        $this->visible = $visible;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function setCategories($categories)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getTitle();
    }
}
```

Category.php Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    public function __construct() {

        $this->recipe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Recipe", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $recipe;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRecipe()
    {
        return $this->recipe;
    }

    public function setRecipe()
    {
        return $this->recipe;
    }

    public function addRecipe(Recipe $recipe): self
    {
        if (!$this->recipe->contains($recipe)) {
            $this->recipe[] = $recipe;
            $recipe->addCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeRecipe(Recipe $recipe): self
    {
        if ($this->recipe->removeElement($recipe)) {
            $recipe->removeCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to init $categories in Recipe constructor

Comment: I did that. You can see it in the Recipe constructor but it doen't runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `multiple` and `expanded` options if you need your EntityType to be a select with multiple choices.

That's why actually it return only one object.

Look at this documentation about `EntityType`
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage

For you it would be something like that :

```
->add('categories',EntityType::class,[
    'class' => Category::class,
    'mapped' => true,
    'label' => 'Categoria',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => false
])
```

Have a look at this table :
https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons

Edit !

I had switch multiple and expanded values ! Of course it should be this :

```
Element Type                            Expanded    Multiple
select tag (with multiple attribute)    false       true
```

My mistake !

Comment: When  I do that I have this error: Entity of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

Comment: You should try to add ``cascade={"persist"}`` on your ``Recipe`` entity.
Like that : 

```@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="recipe", cascade={"persist"})```

Comment: I do that but it don't solve this error.  It's strange because all combinations between multiple and explanded runs. But multiple = false and expanded = true get this error

Comment: @Cristina you're right I had a mistake in my answer by switching both multiple and expanded  !

Comment: I preffer this HTML format: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select why expanded and multiple can't be false? I preffer this HTML format but it doesn't work

Comment: What you want is having multiple ``Category`` for one ``Recipe`` is that correct ?!
Is it working now when you submit the form ? Is the problem now related only to the HTML format ? If so, open a new subject and ask for how to change the display style of the select.

Comment: Yes! It's only about HTML format of select multiple. Thank you so much!!